# Export Excel in golang

Tags: excel, go, excelize

I create an excel template and export it using excelite golang, they open quietly on Linux, but on Windows and Mac, when opening, an error occurs "there is an error in part of the contents in the book.xlsx. Make a recovery attempt? If you trust the source from which the book was obtained, click the "YES" button".I use gin

```
func (r *Router) exportTCMs(ctx *gin.Context) {

    var err error
    defer func() { abortWithStatusJSON(ctx, err) }()

    f := excelize.NewFile()
    defer func() {
        err := f.Close()
        fmt.Println(err)
    }()

    err = r.service.TCM.AllGroupsReportTCM(ctx.Request.Context(), f)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    fName := url.QueryEscape(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02_15_04_05") + ".xlsx")
    f.Path = fName

    ctx.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    ctx.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename*=UTF-8''"+f.Path)
    ctx.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary")

    if err := f.Write(ctx.Writer); err != nil {
        errors.New(http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
        return
    }
    //
    ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, model.ResponseNoContent{Data: model.Empty{}, Message: ""})

}
```

I tried to change the headers, but nothing helps, I don't even know what the problem might be.

Comment: Where's the Excel generation code? `xlsx` files are ZIP packages containing XML files. If Excel itself complains, you don't have an Excel file. It doesn't matter that whatever program you used in Linux didn't complain. That's a bug or "feature" of that program. Some lazy libraries or developers create fake Excel files by saving data as plain text or HTML tables and changing only the extension.

Comment: What happens if you open that file with a text editor? If you see data, it's not an Excel file at all. Excel itself will detect this and try to read it as a *text* or *HTML* file using the culture's default formats and separators. It will still complain about the fake extension

Comment: the file opens normally, but this warning pops up, if I just save the file and open it, then the warning will not appear

Comment: That's not what I asked. Post the code that generates the Excel file. Did you copy it from [this Github issue](https://github.com/qax-os/excelize/issues/148) perhaps? The comments say that this code *doesn't* work and produces incomplete files. In recent versions [you need to use Flush](https://github.com/qax-os/excelize/issues/1180) before calling `Write`

Comment: f := excelize.NewFile()
 defer func() {
  err := f.Close()
  fmt.Println(err)
 }()

 
 ctx.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
 ctx.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename*=UTF-8''"+f.Path)
 ctx.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary")

 if err := f.Write(ctx.Writer); err != nil {
  errors.New(http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
  return
 }

Comment: Try calling `f.Flush()` before `f.Write()`

Comment: func (f *File) Write(w io.Writer, opt ...Options)
func (sw *StreamWriter) Flush() error 
these are different methods, I won't be able to call f.Flush()

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the Go language and Excelize library are you using? Note that, there are some incompatible changes in the Go 1.21.0, the Excelize library can not working with that version normally, if you are using the Go 1.21.x, please upgrade to the Go 1.21.1 and later version.

Comment: After creating the file, I called f.Write() and ctx.Json of the GIN package, commenting out the ctx.Json I managed to overcome this error